# Netbeans & Xdebug Problem: private variables in class methods not visible?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

when I debug my PHP Project using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1  and Xdebug 2.0.5 variables declared in the scope of class methods like *$myVar* in the following example are not visible in the variables-window :

```
class Test
{
  public function test($myVar)
  {
     return $myVar=1+$myVar;
  }

}
```

Though Object-Variables and SuperGlobals are visible.

This is a very annoying behavior as the values of these variables are often important hints for finding bugs.

Is someone facing the same problem?

Is this a normal behavior of XDebug or do I have to change the configuration?

Thanks for any help or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [link](http://icephoenix.us/php/xdebug-doesnt-show-local-variables-in-komodo-netbeans-or-eclipse-pdt/) to solve my issue:

Basically it is a problem with XDebug 2.0.5 and PHP 5.3.2.

To solve this just **upgrade to XDebug 2.1.0**.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn on Watches/Balloons Evaluation in Tools, Options, PHP. But xdebug tends to get unstable when you do that on a large project.

Comment: I tried that, but It didn't work either with local variables in class methods.

Comment: tried today xdebug 2.1.3 for a similar problem and it solve my issue, plus it is far more stable (on php 5.3.5 ubuntu 11.04 at least). Watches works without trouble in this version

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse and local vars are shown, of course given your debug-location is within the variables local scope.

It also isn't related to show_local_vars and collect_params, as I disabled both (confiremd by phpinfo) and Eclipse still keeps track of local variables.

So ... Iam not facing the same problem and it dosn't seem to be the 'normal' behaviour of XDebug and it doesn't seem to be related to your XDebug-settings.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used a quoted value in my apache php.ini and was only able to retrieve the superglobals values which led me to believe the debugger was actually working. 
Apparently you have to use the unquoted value because now I can also see the local variables.

So instead of

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so"
```

Use

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
```

Ubuntu 10.04
PHP 5.3.2
Netbeans 7.1.2
Xdebug 2.2.1